# How to add exactly same right axis on plotly R chart?

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I have this basic script:

```
mtcars %>%
  plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(x = ~mpg, y = ~wt, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers' ) %>%
  layout(yaxis2 = list(overlaying = "y", side = "right", title = 'test'))
```

It plots the chart with one axe on the left even though there is a command in layout to add a second chart.

I suppose it doesn't get triggered because nothing is plotted.

So I add the same variable

```
mtcars %>%
  plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(x = ~mpg, y = ~wt, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers' ) %>%
   add_trace(x = ~mpg, y = ~wt, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers', yaxis = "y2" )  %>%
  layout(yaxis2 = list(overlaying = "y", side = "right", title = 'test'))
```

And in this case both left and right axis are the same.
I suppose I could just do the second series transparent or something.

Is there a more clean solution to force the second axis to show even though nothing is plotted on it?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
library(plotly)
#Code
mtcars %>%
  plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(x = ~mpg, y = ~wt, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers' ) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~mpg, y = ~wt, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers',
            yaxis = "y2") %>%
  layout(yaxis2 = list(overlaying = "y", side = "right", title = 'test'))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is what I had in my second chunk of code (pasted wrong one)
I am aware of this solution but it still shows the label has to render an extra trace

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but anyway:

You can't display an axis without assigning a trace to it.

However, you don't need to use the entire data again - you can simply create datapoints based on `range()` to achive the same an hide the trace via the `opacity` and `showlegend` parameters (using `visible` would prevent showing the axis):

```
library(plotly)

mtcars %>%
  plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(x = ~mpg, y = ~wt, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers') %>%
  add_trace(x = ~range(mpg), y = ~range(wt), type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers', yaxis = "y2", opacity = 0, showlegend = FALSE) %>%
  layout(showlegend = TRUE, yaxis2 = list(overlaying = "y", side = "right", title = 'test'))
```

[image: result]